# \part Heading style

Tags: sectioning, parts

I'm using `\documentclass{book}`. I like to redefine my `\part` style to sth similar to the one in the picture below. So, I like when I use part I get sth similiar to pic below with "Part" instead of chapter on top and a gray rectangle with a number inside. Any ideas how to do that?

[image]

Comment: This is possibly generated by `titlesec` package

Comment: Christian, can you give me a MWC?!

Comment: I am sorry, but I don't know MWC. If you mean an example, both Herbert and Bernard provided nice answers, I can't top at all

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\makeatletter
%\renewcommand\thepart{\arabic{part}}
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\thepart\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
  \reset@font
  \parindent \z@ 
  \vspace*{10\p@}%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{%
      \hsize=7mm%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}p{7mm}@{}}
        \makebox[7mm]{\scshape\strut\small\partname}\\
        \makebox[7mm]{\cellcolor{black}\Huge\color{white}\bfseries\strut\thepart\rule[-4cm]{0pt}{4cm}}%
      \end{tabular}%
      \makebox(0,0){\put(-10,-100){\fbox{\phantom{\rule[-4cm]{7mm}{4cm}}}}}
      }%
    \kern-2pt
    \vbox to 0pt{%
       \tabular[t]{@{}p{1cm}p{\dimexpr\hsize-2.1cm}@{}}\hline
          & \Huge\itshape\rule{0pt}{1.5\ht\strutbox}#1\endtabular}%
    }%
  \cleardoublepage
%  \vskip 100\p@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\part{Books in \LaTeX}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: very nice! I like it a lot. But, I want to be a bit different. 1) Right now in the TOC, I get "I Part I: ..." whereas it should be "Part I: ..." the first number should be dropped. 2) The next page after the part should also be fully empty, right now I get a header  line with a number. It should be just a number in the middle of the page and fully empty. 3) I do like to add a quote after the title of part in the same page. Can we pull the heading a bit higher and then add `epigraph` below that? Thanks a lot!

Comment: did you see my question? I appreciate if you help on that.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution using the `ebgaramond` font and its lettrine initials. I've tried to make the code as generic as possible, but some parameters (used in `raisebox` mainly) may depend on the font. I also tried to make the result as close as possible to the O.P.'s picture, plus some colour. The formatting of part titles is made with `titlesec`.

**Added**: I managed to add `epigraphs` on part pages, with the `environ` and `etoolbox` packages. The command to be used is `\thispartepigrah{text}{source}`. It set a boolean `withepi` to true that allows an epigraph to be displayed as an optional argument to `\titleformat`, then resets withepi to `false`. The `epigraph` command itself is captured through a fake environment, `PartEpigraph`.

```
    \documentclass[12pt]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{microtype} 
    \usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage{garamondx}%%
    \usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{epigraph}
    \usepackage{environ} 

    \setlength\epigraphwidth{0.5\linewidth}
    \newbool{withepi}
    \NewEnviron{PartEpigraph}
    {\global\let\mypartepigraph\BODY}%
    \newcommand\thispartepigraph[2]{%
    \setbool{withepi}{true}%
    \begin{PartEpigraph}
      \epigraph{#1}{#2}
    \end{PartEpigraph}}%

    \usepackage{geometry}
    \usepackage{titlesec}%[newparttoc]
    \usepackage{lettrine}
    \renewcommand\LettrineFontHook{\fontfamily{EBGaramondInitials-TLF}\color{titlecolour}}
    %

    \setlength\fboxrule{0.6pt}
    \colorlet{titlecolour}{DarkSeaGreen4!80}
    \newlength\labelframewd
    \settowidth{\labelframewd}{~\footnotesize\textsc{part}~}

    \newsavebox\partlabelbox%

    \newcommand\partlabel{%
    \makebox[0pt]{\fcolorbox{titlecolour}{titlecolour}{%
    \raisebox{8.4ex}[0pt]{\rlap{\hspace{-\fboxsep}\resizebox*{\dimexpr\labelframewd+2\fboxsep\relax}{!}{\color{titlecolour}\lsstyle\scshape\scriptsize{part}}}}%
    \usebox{\partlabelbox}}}
    \hskip-\fboxsep\color{titlecolour}{\raisebox{-9ex}{\fbox{\phantom{\usebox{\partlabelbox}}}}}
    }%

    \titleformat{\part}[display]{}
    {%
    \sbox{\partlabelbox}{\raisebox{0pt}[7ex][27ex]{\resizebox{\labelframewd}{!}{\hfill\color{white}{\arabic{part}}\hfill}}}
    \smash{\partlabel}}%
    {6ex}
    {\thispagestyle{empty}{\color{titlecolour}\titlerule[\fboxrule]}\vskip2.5ex\hspace*{3\labelframewd}\fontsize{32}{40}\itshape}%
    [\ifbool{withepi}{\vspace{4\baselineskip}\mypartepigraph\global\setbool{withepi}{false}}{}]

    \titlespacing{\part}{0pt}{1.25\baselineskip}{10\baselineskip}
    \renewcommand*\thepart{\arabic{part}}

    \begin{document} 

    \thispartepigraph{For the Snark \emph{was} a Boojum,  you see.}{Lewis Carroll     --- \emph{The Hunting of the Snark}}

    \part{Books in \LaTeX}

    \lettrine{T}{ext} text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I actually need a `\part` style not a `\chapter` style. I need the heading design on top of the page as you gave and an epigraph below that, not text on that page and of course another fully empty page after that. Could you please modify it that way?

Comment: @LatexQuest: I updated my answer to a part instead of a chapter, and also the possibilty of epigraphs, to be introduced with a `thispartepigraph{…}{…}` command just before `\part{…}`.