# ToC entry formatting

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using the code below to redefine my `\part` style. I want to modify it so that I see "Part I: A Test ... " with \scshape font in the TOC. Right Now, in the TOC I see "I A Test ... ". How should I modify my code?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\part}[display]
  {\Huge\scshape\filright}
  {\partname~\thepart:}
  {20pt}
  {\thispagestyle{epigraph}}
\makeatother
\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}


\begin{document}

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that     dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combining and adapting answers to other of your questions ([Redefine \part style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192851/3954) and [\part Heading style](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/192838/3954)) and adding the formatting for the part entries in the ToC, this might be what you're after:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \thispagestyle{epigraph}
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart:\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
  \reset@font
  \parindent \z@ 
  \vspace*{-400\p@}%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{%
      \hsize=7mm%
      \begin{tabular}{@{}p{7mm}@{}}
        \makebox[7mm]{\scshape\strut\small\partname}\\
        \makebox[7mm]{\cellcolor{black}\Huge\color{white}\bfseries\strut\thepart\rule[-4cm]{0pt}{4cm}}%
      \end{tabular}%
      \makebox(0,0){\put(-10,-100){\fbox{\phantom{\rule[-4cm]{7mm}{4cm}}}}}
      }%
    \kern-2pt
    \vbox to 0pt{%
       \tabular[t]{@{}p{1cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\hsize-2.1cm}@{}}\hline
          & \Huge\itshape\rule{0pt}{1.5\ht\strutbox}#1\endtabular}%
    }%
  \cleardoublepage
%  \vskip 100\p@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

The resulting document:

[image]

A close-up to the ToC:

[image]

Invert the order in which the decorative elements are drawn in the part headings and you can use any color instead of black:

```
\documentclass[draft]{book}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{epigraph}

\setlength\epigraphwidth{.6\textwidth}

\makeatletter
\def\@part[#1]#2{%
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >-2\relax
     \thispagestyle{epigraph}
      \refstepcounter{part}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{\partname~\thepart:\hspace{1em}#1}%
    \else
      \addcontentsline{toc}{part}{#1}%
    \fi
    \markboth{}{}%
  \reset@font
  \parindent \z@ 
  \vspace*{-400\p@}%
  \hbox{%
    \vbox{%
      \hsize=7mm%
     \makebox(0,0){\put(10,-100){\fbox{\phantom{\rule[-4cm]{7mm}{4cm}}}}}%
     \begin{tabular}{@{}p{7mm}@{}}
        \makebox[7mm]{\scshape\strut\small\partname}\\
        \makebox[7mm]{\cellcolor{gray}\Huge\color{white}\bfseries\strut\thepart\rule[-4cm]{0pt}{4cm}}%
      \end{tabular}%
      }%
    \kern6pt
    \vbox to 0pt{%
       \tabular[t]{@{}p{1cm}>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{\dimexpr\hsize-2.55cm}@{}}\hline
          & \Huge\itshape\rule{0pt}{1.5\ht\strutbox}#1\endtabular}%
    }%
  \cleardoublepage
%  \vskip 100\p@
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\cleardoublepage

\epigraphhead[450]{Fairy tales are more than true: not because they tell us that dragons exist, but because they tell us dragons can be beaten.\par\hfill\textsc{C.K. Chesterton}}
\part{A Test Part Title}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is awesome! Two birds, one stone! Just a question, right now my next page after the `\part` page is not fully empty. Yours has a number on top, mine has a number and a line. How can I push it to be fully empty?

Comment: @LatexQuest impossible to tell without seeing the code you are using. How can we know where the line comes from if you don't provide the code that is responsible for it? In any case, loading the `emptypage` package `\usepackage{emptypage}` in the preamble might give you what you need.

Comment: How about a question on your code? Assume I want to use gray color for the upper rectangle instead of black. Then the black lines of the lower rectangle will show up, which wouldn't look nice. Can we set the upper rectangle to appear on a top layer so that the overlapping parts from the lower rectangle disappear? [To see what I mean, simply modify => `\cellcolor{gray}`.

Comment: @LatexQuest please see my updated answer.

Comment: Is it possible to activate line breaks in the `\part` title? When it is relatively long it starts breaking the words and hyphenating them ... would be nice to be able to put break lines in the middle.

Comment: @LatexQuest What do you mean with "activate line breaks"? Line breaks are there by default. Do you mean suppress hyphenation?

Comment: I want to be able to break the title like => \part{A Test\\ Part Title}. Right Now, I cannot do it!

Comment: Why can't you do it? What happens? Do you get errors or what? Please clearly explain. More importantly, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Just compile your own code by my modification. Two things happen. 1) The part heading style will be corrupted. The second line goes below the rectangles. 2) The ToC will be broken into two lines. I guess the latter should be solved using `\addcontentsline` or sth like that, right?

Comment: I want to do that because sometimes my part titles are too long. In that case they will be hyphenated and justified, which I don't like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15960/discussion-between-latexquest-and-gonzalo-medina).